# What is the derivative of $J(s)=\alpha { s }^{ T }(I-W)s+(1-\alpha ){ \left\| s-h \right\| }_{ F }^{ 2 }$ w.r.t. $s$?

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative

$\alpha$ is a scalar, $W$ is a matrix, s and h are vectors, I is identity matrix.
I know the derivative is as follows:
$\frac { \partial J(s) }{ \partial s } =2(I-\alpha W)s+2(1-\alpha )h\quad$

but I am wondering about the steps. I don't get the above results according to the hints in matrix cookbook. Anybody can help me?

Comment: The result seems wrong if $W$ isn’t symmetric.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that, $W$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denoting the scalar product in a more legible form we have
$$\begin{align}
D_vJ(s)&=D_v(\alpha\langle s,(I-W)s\rangle+(1-\alpha)\|s-h\|^2\\
&=\alpha\bigl(\langle v,(I-W)s\rangle+\langle s,(I-W)v\rangle\bigr)+\\
&\quad +2(1-\alpha)\langle s-h,v\rangle\\
&=\alpha\bigl(\langle v,s\rangle-\langle v,Ws\rangle
+\langle s,v\rangle-\langle s,Wv\rangle\bigr)+\\
&\quad+2\langle s,v\rangle-2\alpha\langle s,v\rangle
+2(1-\alpha)\langle h,v\rangle\\
&=2\langle s,v-\alpha Wv\rangle +2(1-\alpha)\langle h,v\rangle\\
&=2\langle (I-\alpha W)s+(1-\alpha)h,v\rangle
\end{align},$$
that is 
$$\nabla J(s)=2(I-\alpha W)s+2(1-\alpha)h$$
as claimed.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot. Is there any book in which these kinds of operations are explained?

Comment: You’re welcome. Essentially, I’ve only used the product rule.